# Get index of last previous match in DataFrame column

Tags: python, dataframe, string-matching

I have a dataframe, trans_df, of stock buy and sell transactions.  I am trying to create a column that totals all the previous transactions and another column that would add the current transaction to this cumulative previous transaction amount.

My input df looks like this:

```html
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="border: none;border-collapse: collapse;width:194pt;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;border:.5pt solid windowtext;height:14.4pt;width:98pt;">date</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;border:.5pt solid windowtext;border-left:none;width:48pt;">ticker</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;border:.5pt solid windowtext;border-left:none;width:48pt;">quantity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2020-01-08</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">MMM</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2020-01-08</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">RUN</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2020-01-09</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">AAPL</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2020-02-10</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">RUN</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2020-03-16</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">MMM</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2021-01-09</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">F</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2021-01-10</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">MMM</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2021-01-11</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">RUN</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2021-01-12</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">RUN</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2021-01-13</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">AAPL</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:general;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;text-align:center;height:14.4pt;">2021-01-14</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">MMM</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;text-align:right;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;">6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What i want in the end is this:

```html
<table style="border: none;width:373.0pt;margin-left:-.05pt;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;border: 1pt solid windowtext;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: top;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><strong><span style="color:black;">date</span></strong></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext currentcolor;border-style: solid solid solid none;border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt medium;border-image: none 100% / 1 / 0 stretch;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: top;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><strong><span style="color:black;">ticker</span></strong></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext currentcolor;border-style: solid solid solid none;border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt medium;border-image: none 100% / 1 / 0 stretch;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: top;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><strong><span style="color:black;">quantity</span></strong></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext currentcolor;border-style: solid solid solid none;border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt medium;border-image: none 100% / 1 / 0 stretch;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: top;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><strong><span style="color:black;">last_entry</span></strong></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext currentcolor;border-style: solid solid solid none;border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt medium;border-image: none 100% / 1 / 0 stretch;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: top;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><strong><span style="color:black;">prev_units</span></strong></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext currentcolor;border-style: solid solid solid none;border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt medium;border-image: none 100% / 1 / 0 stretch;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: top;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><strong><span style="color:black;">cml_units</span></strong></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2020-01-08</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">MMM</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">1</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;"><br></td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">0</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">1</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2020-01-08</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">RUN</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">10</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;"><br></td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">0</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">5</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2020-01-09</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">AAPL</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">10</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;"><br></td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">0</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">10</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2020-02-10</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">RUN</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">20</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">1</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">5</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">25</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2020-03-16</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">MMM</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">0</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">1</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">3</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2021-01-09</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">F</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">5</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;"><br></td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">0</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2021-01-10</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">MMM</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">3</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">5</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">3</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">6</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2021-01-11</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">RUN</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">30</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">4</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">25</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">55</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2021-01-12</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">RUN</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">-5</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">8</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">55</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">50</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2021-01-13</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">AAPL</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">-5</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">10</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">5</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 98pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">2021-01-14</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="color:black;">MMM</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 48pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">6</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 77pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">7</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 53pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">6</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 49pt;padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 0.2in;vertical-align: bottom;">
                <p style='margin:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><span style="color:black;">12</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

last_entry = the index starting with 0 of the last previous match of the ticker.
prev_units = the cml_units of the last previous match, i.e. the value in column cml_units where the index is equal to the value in last_entry
cml_units = merely the sum of the quantity column + prev_units column

Here's my code to get the indexes of all the previous matches:

```
for t in (set(trans_df['ticker'])):
print (np.insert(trans_df[trans_df['ticker']==t].index.values.astype(np.float32),0,np.nan)[:-1])
```

If the column last_entry isn't needed, we can skip that one, if there is another way to get the aggregated quantities up until the current row.

Answer (score 0):

My friend David showed me how to do it for a single ticker quite easily:

```
trans_df.loc[trans_df['ticker'] == 'MMM', 'cml_units']= trans_df.loc[trans_df['ticker'] == 'MMM', 'quantity'].cumsum()
```

Which I was then able to extend using groupby:

```
trans_df['cml_units']=trans_df.groupby('ticker')['quantity'].cumsum()
```

The above code helps, but I think I may still need to get the index of the previous ticker match, as I need to also keep track of the previous average cost.  When I have a sale of a stock, I need to deduct the product of the average cost times the number of shares sold, to determine the gain/loss on the sale and to correctly adjust the cumsum of the cml_cost.